# Pressing to any link with image sends the form to the server, html

Tags: html, image, forms

I work with Grails 2.0.1
I have such problem:

I have table with data inside the `<g:form>...</g:form>` tag.
Each row in the table has two links: delete and edit current row.
Here is one of them:

```
<a onclick="deleteDialog(${speciality?.id})" class="delBtn">
      <input type="image" src="<g:createLinkTo dir="/images/ctrl" file="del.jpg"/>"/>
</a>
```

When I click on edit link the confirmation message have to be displayed. But when I click it form is sent to server, like I clicked on submitButton.
If link doesn't contain an image everything works fine.

So, how can I use links with images inside?

Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, `input` elements are not allowed inside `a` elements (for obvious reasons).

Comment: thanks for you quick answer. It helped me to solve the problem

Comment: "obvious reasons" ?? 
Could you elaborate a bit on them ? (I take the risk to sound stupid)

Comment: @Euloiix I have changed <input type="image" ... /> to <img .../>  <input type="image".../> works like a submit button and sends form when you click it

Comment: And that's why its not allowed ? I understand but you can do that as easily using Javascript and Ajax, can't you ?

Comment: I don't understand why I should use Javascript and Ajax to work with links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks much four your comments.
I have changed `<input type="image" ... />` to `<img .../>` to fix this problem